# How does the Time Stop spell work when being grappled?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, grapple

If a creature is grappled and then casts Time Stop, are they able to escape from the grapple?

Also, if they *can* escape from the grapple:
Since the creature they're grappled by would be under the effect of Time Stop, do they still have to make the grapple escape DC, or would they just have to use an action and not have to roll for it?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] if you haven't already. This is a great first question! Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: It's great that [Tim C's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/147754/48759) helped you. However is can be a good idea  to [wait 24 hours to accept an answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8630/48759) to allow time for all other timezones to see and answer your question. You may find one you like more. This isn't a policy and you can accept or change your accepted answer at any time. Just letting you know since you are new around here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There are no rules which dictate interactions between Time Stop and being Grappled

There is no provision in the Time Stop spell to clear the Grappled condition (or any other condition), and no provision in the Grappled condition that indicates Time Stop would clear it (unless the Grappler can be considered incapacitated). Since (when discussing RAW) spells only do what they say they do, this means that casting Time Stop *does not* clear the Grappled condition on the caster.

This means that the caster's movement speed is zero (per Grappled condition) until they use an action to escape.

> **Escaping a Grapple.** A grappled creature can use its action to escape. To do so, it must succeed on a Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check contested by [the grappler's] Strength (Athletics) check.

Since, again, there are no rules that say otherwise, the grappler would still be entitled to a Strength (Athletics) check to prevent the caster from escaping.

Escaping a grapple does not affect any creature besides the caster, however, so doing so would (at least) not end the Time Stop.

### However, there is a negative interaction between Time Stop and being the one doing the grappling

Either moving or releasing a grappled creature do affect another creature (the grappled creature). If the caster had initiated a grapple (or counter-grappled to avoid being dragged around), taking either action would (under RAW) end the Time Stop; and the caster would have to either remain in place or end the spell early.

### Both of these are based on legalistic interpretations of Rules as Written

As with anything in D&D, these are subject to DM's ruling.

At my table, I would probably give the caster Advantage on escaping grapples, and allow them to release creatures (but not drag them around) without ending the Time Stop.

Comment: For that matter, the text of the spell is open to really funky interpretations: "No time passes for other creatures, while you take 1d4 + 1 turns in a row, during which you can use actions and *move as normal*."; but also: "This spell ends if one of the actions you use during this period, or any effects that you create during this period, affects a creature other than you".